# Need to populate a field when 'specific' text is added to a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

As stated by my headline, I would like to accomplish the following based on this image that I made, and hopefully, it makes sense. I've done something similar to this function but can't quite remember what it is I'm missing.

[image: Sample]

The formula I have attempted to do on my own (below). Please let me know what I am missing or if I'm over complicating the formula or just not thinking about this the right way.

**Access to my sheet:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_HtEmzJgG5hLxU426JSYgr03g6TJGtl7qbpaY7jk2AI/edit?usp=sharing

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY("♂"&UPPER(TRIM(IFERROR(
 SPLIT('Sheet 1'!A2:A, ","))))&"♀"&'Sheet 1'!B2:B, , 999^99)), , 999^99), "♂")), "♀"), 0), 2, 0)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple `VLOOKUP` solves this...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D, 'Sheet 1'!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew I over complicated this. I'll upvote as soon as I'm able, it won't let me for some reason.

Comment: @MikelTan you can upvote when you gain 25+ rep points. until then you are able to accept the answer as correct if it solved your problem

Comment: I do have one more question, if I want the VLOOKUP to say look at two columns but their not next to each other, EXAMPLE: Sheet 1 has 3 columns, A,B and C.  And I want to look at Colum A and Column C only. Would the formula change to =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D, 'Sheet 1'!A2:A, 'Sheet 1'!C2:C, 2,)))

Comment: it could be: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D, 'Sheet 1'!A:C, 3, 0)))`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. So the colon acts as a seperator, and the numera evaluates the amount of arguements? 3 for three columns, but what is the 0 used for?

Comment: 0 is for "exact match" and 3 = "3rd column from A:C"

Comment: Sweet, I understand, thanks again, have a great day!